# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_*^{(n)}\|_1^{\frac{1}{n}}=\|\hat{f}\|_\infty$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, convolution

Let $1<p\leq 2$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{T})$, i.e. $f$ is $p-$th power integrable and is $1-$periodic. Define
$$f_*^{(n)}=f*f*\dots*f\quad n\text{ times}$$
Show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_*^{(n)}\|_1^{\frac{1}{n}}=\|\hat{f}\|_\infty$$
where
$$\|\hat{f}\|_\infty=\max_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}|\hat{f}(j)|$$

My attempt:

By Hausdorff-Young inequality, we have
$$\|f_*^{(n)}\|_1\geq \|\widehat{f_*^{(n)}}\|_\infty=\|\hat{f}\|_\infty^n$$
Therefore
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\|f_*^{(n)}\|_1^{\frac{1}{n}}\geq\|\hat{f}\|_\infty$$
The difficult part is to prove that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|f_*^{(n)}\|_1^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq\|\hat{f}\|_\infty$$
which I have no idea how to deal with. Any suggestions for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is simply not true for $1<p\le 2$. For example let $f(t)=\sin(t)/t$; then $||\hat f||_\infty<\infty$ but $||f^{(n)}||_1=\infty$ for every $n$. Are you sure this is what the problem asked? (For $p=1$ it's a consequence of the Spectral Radius Formula in a Banach algebra...)

Comment: It's a straightforward question if you have the $L^2$ norm instead of the $L^1$ norm as $\hat{f * g}=\hat{f} \hat{g}$ and $||f||_2 = ||\hat{f}||_2$. Maybe that's what's desired?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This is indeed the question asked which I'm pretty sure. I think the function $\frac{\sin t}{t} $ does not satisfy the $1-$periodic condition, thus it does not work, am I correct?

Comment: @nayrb Well, the question I posted is the original one I have which I am pretty sure.

Comment: @FrankLu OH. I read it as a problem about $L^p(\Bbb R)$. The story's different for $L^p(\Bbb T)$. Sorry...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That's no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your second inequality, do the following.

First, show that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||f^{(n)}_*||_2^{1/n} = ||\hat{f}||_\infty.$$

To do this, note that $$||f^{(n)}_*||_2^{1/n} = ||(\hat{f})^n||_2^{1/n} = ||\hat{f}^2||_n^{1/2} \to ||\hat{f}^2||_\infty^{1/2}$$
as $n \to \infty$. We've used norm equivalence in $L^2$, properties of transforms of convolutions, and the fact that $||g||_n \to ||g||_\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Now can you show the $L^2$ norm controls the $L^1$ norm (i.e., find the useful inequality here to finish)?

Comment: Indeed.. very clear and elegant. Thanks.