# $\|\hat{f} \|_{\infty} = \lim _ {n \rightarrow \infty} (\|f^{(n)}\|_1)^{1/n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f \in L^2 \cap L^1$ on the Real line, and define $f^{(n)}$ to be the $n$-fold convolution $f \circ f ... \circ f $.

I want to show that $||\hat{f} ||_{\infty} = \lim _ {n \rightarrow \infty} (||f^{(n)}||_1)^{1/n}$, using the tools of Fourier analysis on $L_1$ and $L_2$.

And actually I'm only stuck on the fact that the RHS $\le$ LHS.
A formal proof would be something like this, but I'm stuck on technicalities:

\begin{align}\lim_n (\|f^{(n)}\|_1)^{1/n} &= \lim_n [\int f^{(n)} \overline{\exp{ (i \arg f^{(n)})}}]^{1/n} 
 = \lim_n \left\langle f^{(n)}, \exp{ (i \arg f^{(n)})}\right\rangle  ^{1/n}\\  
& = \lim_n \left\langle\widehat{f^{(n)}}, \widehat{\exp{ (i \arg f^{(n)})}}\right\rangle^{1/n}  
 = \lim_n \left\langle{\hat{f}^n}, \widehat{\exp{ (i \arg f^{(n)})}}\right\rangle^{1/n}  \\
& = \lim_n \left[\int \hat{f}^n \overline{\widehat{\exp{ (i \arg f^{(n)})}}}\right]^{1/n}  
 \le \lim_n \left[\| \hat{f} \|^n _\infty\int \overline{\widehat{\exp{ (i \arg f^{(n)})}}}\right]^{1/n}  
 \le \|\hat{f}\|_\infty
\end{align}

Trouble is, $\exp{ (i \arg f^{(n)})}$ is not integrable since its magnitude is always 1. I have tried to do an approach where I insert $g_k$ where $g_k$ is a compact smooth "hill" function which becomes wider and wider and limits to $1$, and this allows me to arrive at

\begin{align}
\lim_n (||f^n||_1)^{1/n} &= \lim_n \lim_k [\int f^{(n)} \overline{g_k \exp{ (i \arg f^{(n)})}}]^{1/n} \\  
 &\le \lim_n \lim_k \left[\| \hat{f} \|^n _\infty\int \overline{\widehat{g_k \exp{ (i \arg f^{(n)})}}}\right]^{1/n}\\
& \le \| \hat{f} \|_\infty \lim_n \lim_k \int \overline{\widehat{g_k \exp{ (i \arg f^{(n)})}}}]^{1/n} 
\end{align}

But I can't actually take the limit $k$ because then the term will go to infinity. I thought of making $k$ a function of $n$ but then I couldn't show that this doesn't change the limit.

This strategy is taken from an analogous proof on the periodic circle with discrete Fourier transform, and I would like to see if it can be fixed somehow (because this was the hint given by the text).

Comment: the fact that $\|\hat{f}\|_\infty = \lim_n (\|\hat{f}^n\|_2^2)^{1/2n} =\lim_n (\|f^{(n)}\|_2^2)^{1/2n}$ is probably useful (and hill function is called a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function))

Comment: You may want to look at this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495646/show-that-lim-n-to-infty-f-n-1-frac1n-hatf-infty/1495690#1495690

Comment: It seems like the above link only work for finite measure spaces?

Comment: Almost duplicate of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664286/self-convolution-of-an-l2-function/1664793#1664793 (and see my answer there perhaps)

Comment: Yes if we restrict to the circle I think the proof will come out fine. Is there a way to reduce to that case from the real line?

Comment: What do you have in mind when you say "using the tools of Fourier analysis in L1 and L2"? What would you like to exclude?

Comment: I am asking because this is a classical result, and it relates to the spectrum of convolution operators, and I want to confirm you are trying to sidestep applications of functional analysis.

Comment: Yes I am looking for a proof as close as possible to the attempt in my post.

Comment: The reason is that this exercise comes from a text about Fourier integrals. So presumably I am to gain some intuition about Fourier transform via this exercise.

Answer (score 5):

@Romain and @Glitch pointed errors or gaps in an answer I posted some time ago. As @David points out, the result is true, even without the assumption the $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I cannot fix my proof, hence I am deleting it.

If someone adds a proof later on, I will completely remove my post.

Comment: How do you justify  $\int \int |f^{(n-1)}(x)| |f(y-x)| dy dx 
= \int \int |f^{(n-1)}(x)| \; |f(y)|^{ } dy dx$

Comment: You've seen double integrals before, right?

Comment: I have even seen triple integrals :)

Comment: So did you figure it out how to do the change of variables?

Comment: Certainly it's true for $f\in L^1$. This is just the Spectral Radius Formula from Banach algebras, plus the fact that the Fourier transform gives all the complex homomorphisms of $L^1$.

Comment: Yes I got it, but now I'm wondering about the Cauchy Schwartz-like inequality that comes next. If it is C.S., what is the vector space? Is it over $R^2$ or $R$?

Comment: I think there were some errors. I edited the chain of inequalities. The Cauchy  Schawartz point to go from L1 to L2 is Young's inequality, a special case of which says $\| G\ast f \|_p \le  \| G \|_p  \|  f \|_1 $, i.e.: convolution with an $L^1$ function maps $L^p$ to $L^p$. In this case I am applying it with $G=f^{(n-2)} \in L^2(\mathbb R)$

Comment: Okay so you want $||G \ast f||_1 \le ||G||_2 ||f||_1$  where $G = f^{(n-2)}$? I'm not familiar with Young's inequality but following the notation from the Wikipedia entry you would need $1/p + 1/q = 1/r + 1$ i.e. $1 + 1/2 = 1 + 1$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality#Young.27s_inequality_for_convolutions

Comment: My nth mistake. Correcting soon.

Comment: Corrected. Getting there by succesive approximations. :)

Comment: By the way, what I am doing is a variation on your idea. $exp( i \space arg f^{(n)} )$ is not integrable, so I am peeling factors from $f^{(n)}$ to get convergence. I messed the implementation for working while tired...

Comment: After the change into Fourier space did you want exponentiation or convolution? $\hat{f}^{n}$ vs $\hat{f}^{(n)}$

Comment: I think there might be a mistake: a prior, you don't know that $\|{f}\|_{2/3}$ is finite, hence these estimates could be meaningless...

Comment: @Romain Thanks for pointing to the mistake. In addition to your objection, Young's inequality applies to $p,q,r \ge 1$, thus $q=2/3$ is non-sense$|. I replaced the original argument with one that borrows from a possible proof of the Spectral Radious Formula.

Comment: @VictorZurkowski Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't the new argument (2) reprove the bound from (1), namely that $\Vert \hat{f} \Vert_{\infty} \le L$ rather than the needed bound $\Vert \hat{f} \Vert_{\infty} \ge L$?